# Writing a dict to flat file without brackets in python

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have this dict:

```
my_dict = {'1': {'a', 'b'},
          '2': {'b', 'd'},
          '3': {'c'}
          }
```

I need to write it to a flat file then I wrote this code:

```
with open("myfile", 'w') as f:
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, value))
```

I got this:

```
2 {'d', 'b'}
1 {'b', 'a'}
3 {'c'}
```

It works (order doesn't matter) but I need the output file without any extra character, just the values of the dict keys and values itself, something like this:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `set` items to string using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) before write to the file:

```
>>> ' '.join({'d', 'b'})
'b d'
```

---

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    f.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, ' '.join(value)))
```